# gruntjs doesn't run properly on sass

Tags: javascript, css, sass, gruntjs

Been debugging for hours now..

The livereload worked when I save my .html file, but not for my .scss, anything wrong I did in my config below? No error show in the terminal and console of Chrome.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        watch: {
            sass: {
                files: ['components/sass/*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['sass']
            },
            livereload: {
                files: ['*.html', '*.php', 'js/**/*.{js,json}', 'css/*.css','img/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            }
        },
        sass: {
            options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                outputStyle: 'compressed'
            },
            files: {
                'css/styles.css': 'components/sass/styles.scss'
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass', 'watch']);
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `options.livereload` to your `watch.sass` as well:

```
watch: {
        sass: {
            files: ['components/sass/*.{scss,sass}'],
            tasks: ['sass'],
            options: {
                livereload: true
            }
        },
// ...
```

I've had the same issue, I believe (not 100% sure though) this is caused by watch not triggering 2 tasks if they're too close in time:

1. you modify your sass, this triggers watch
2. your sass creates css
3. the css creation should trigger watch but it does not because it was triggered in 1. a few milliseconds ago

Comment: first line of my answer :) that way watch is triggered only once but it both creates css and starts reload